wol command seemingly not sending wake on lan packet
Problem: wake on lan packet not being sent to turn on a LG tv.
System: Gentoo Linux desktop and laptop
Problem confirmation:
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 udp port 9

showed no broadcast packets being sent.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Solution:
For some reason the WoL packet would be sent to the wrong broadcast address, which prevented the router from broadcasting it. An example of this connecting to a vpn could make it fail for local devices. This is because WoL uses a layer 1 address which lacks routing information.
Turns out to prevent this, the broadcast address may need to be specified. This can be determined with ip a
ip a
1: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:ff:4f:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp5s0
    inet 10.0.0.3/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0

The brd field has the broadcast address so in this case the wol command would be as follows:
wol --host=10.255.255.255 [mac address here]

Hope this unfrizzles someone's grizzle.
